# Methods of polynomials division

Tags: polynomials

How does the division method for polynomial discovered. I have read about ruffini method, it needs divisor to be binomial and linear, I tried to understand horner's method, but couldn't. but methods are traditional and different from what I am doing (like this one below):
[image]

How this method (image one) came from earlier methods?

Comment: Do You remember the method to divide integers by hand? Polymomial rings have essentially the same structure as the ring of integers.

Comment: Is this fact known in earlier time, then what are horner's and ruffini method

Comment: Did ruffini know that dividing polynomials is similar to how integer division works

Comment: How it came to know that polynomial division is similar to as in integer case

Comment: I´m afraid I don´t know, maybe this is rather well posted at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I like the following way:
$$2x^3-7x^2+11=2x^3-6x^2-x^2+3x-3x+9+2=(x-3)(2x^2-x-3)+2.$$

Comment: But this splitting may not be sometimes foundable

Comment: @user629353 See please better my solution. We can detect it always. I think, it's much more better than to write that you wrote. Give me another polynomials and I'll make it again.

Comment: Can someone, which down voted my post, explain me your step?

Comment: Yeah, it's better, thanks

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

So you are asking how the long division that people usually use(i.e. the long division) was derived or infered from the simple ones such as the ruffini method. I'm not sure but you could show that ruffini method is special case of the long division. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nlMXVrgtjw&feature=youtu.be) is a youtube video showing how they are related for a special case.

Comment: If synthetic division comes from ruffini method then how did ruffini found it